# php add array to array without key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an API that I need to write to that expects

```
$foo = array(
  'tags[]' => array('one','two','three','four')
);
```

My array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] =>  two
    [2] =>  three
    [3] =>  four
    [4] =>  five
    [5] =>  six
)
```

I've tried adding the array

```
$foo = array(
  'tags[]' => array($arr)
);
```

But this prints 'Array' once in the database. How do I add the values from $arr to the tags[]?

Comment: why is there `'` after `tags[]`?

Comment: Correct your code before get an answer.

Comment: If you see `Array`, then you are converting your array to a string.  You can't store an array in a database, only strings.  Maybe you want to `json_encode($arr)`?

Comment: Looks like you've got an extra ' and you unintentionally stringified the `array($arr)` that you pass, which then gets inserted.

Comment: Use json_encode on array to save on database, and json_decode to revert from db.

Comment: I suggest using serialize($arr) and unserialize($dbvalue) instead of json_encoding. When you json_decode back the string, an object will be returned instead of an array.

Comment: Corrected the above formatting, this is now correct.

Comment: Why you need `[]` after `tags`?

Comment: I get {"messages":{"tags":"This value should be of type array."},"error":"invalid"} if it isn't

Answer (score 1):

Your `tags[]` array is one level too deep. It should be:

```
$foo = array(
  'tags[]' => $arr
);
```

Note how `$arr` is not wrapped in `array()`.

If you don't remove the `array()` then it looks like:

```
$foo = array(
  'tags[]' => array(
      array('one', 'two', 'three')
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this give me {"messages":{"tags":["This value is not valid.","This value is not valid.","This value is not valid.","This value is not valid.","This value is not valid."]},"error":"invalid"}

Comment: You will have to look at the API source code or documentation to find out the problem. Either it wants a different format or the content of the tags you're passing is invalid according to the API.

Comment: I know  array('one','two','three','four') work. just that I doesn't like the key value of the array, it just expects value.

Comment: `array('one','two','three','four')` is same as `array('0'=>'one', '1'=>'two', '2'=>'three', '3'=>'four', '4'=>'five', '5'=>'six')`